# Chi Square goodness of fit for exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

The issue im having here is figuring out lambda. I know under the null we are testing if the bins come from a exponential distributions with lambda=2. Would this be the lambda I use to calculate the probabilities and expected values for each cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to use $\lambda=2$ to calculate the expected count for each cell.